# Trying to get divisor that produces a quotient within a range

Tags: java, math, processing

This is for a visualization I am working on. I want to divide a rectangle in N equal parts. I want these parts to have a width of say (min. 1px, max 1.5px), depending on the width of the rectangle and I want this division to end with a remainder of 0 (so I don't have a larger than the rest part).

I have tried implementing Modulo: https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html but I am not sure this is the correct way. Any ideas?

```
//Generates coordinates within each line.
for (int j = 0; j < line_coordinates.length; j++) { 

  //Positions start of line draw on random X coordinate.
  float xv = component_x1 + (j * (component_length / line_coordinates.length+1));
  float yv = line_height;

  //Defines available with for each item in a component.
  float item_availablewidth = component_length / line_coordinates.length+1;

  //Creates vector with X coordinate and Y noise affected coordinate.
  line_coordinates[j] = new PVector(xv, y); 

  rectMode(CENTER);
  noStroke();
  fill(232, 45, 34);     
  rect(line_coordinates[j].x,
       line_coordinates[j].y - (line_height / 2),
       item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient,
       line_height);
  println("line_coordinates[j].x1", 
          line_coordinates[j].x - ((item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient) / 2)); //This is where X starts.
  println("line_coordinates[j].x2",
          line_coordinates[j].x + ((item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient) / 2)); //This is where X is supposed to end.

    //This is the first method I tried but I found out this separation needs to be dynamic.
    float drawnline_separation = 2;

    float drawnline_total = (item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient) / drawnline_separation;
    println("drawnline_total", 
            drawnline_total);

    //For loop divides each item in vertical -axidrawable- lines separating them by a max 
    for (int l = 0; l <= drawnline_total; l++) {
      float drawnline_x = lerp(line_coordinates[j].x - ((item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient) / 2),
                     line_coordinates[j].x + ((item_availablewidth * item_randomwidthcoefficient) / 2),
                     l/drawnline_total);
                     println("drawnline_x", drawnline_x);
      stroke(23);
      noFill();

      //Draws line.
      line(drawnline_x, 
           line_coordinates[j].y, 
           drawnline_x, 
           line_coordinates[j].y + 25 );

    }
 } 

//This is the print I am getting. 
line_coordinates[j].x1 346.42535 
line_coordinates[j].x2 353.44092 
drawnline_total 3.5077777 
drawnline_x 346.42535 
drawnline_x 348.42535 
drawnline_x 350.42535 
drawnline_x 352.42535
```

I hope I am being clear! Please let me know if my explanation is very confusing.

[image: Drawing screenshot. Red is for the original rectangle, black for lines that divide it.]